# Does linux have any macro to check whether current CPU core is executed in interrupt context?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I have some code which I don't want to be executed from interrupt context. To detect this, I want to trigger BUG() from my code, but I need some macro which will tell me whether my code executed from interrupt handler or not.
Does Linux have such macro?

Comment: in_irq()? See preempt.h for details

Comment: @Alex Hoppus Thank you!

Comment: @AlexHoppus, I guess `in_interrupt()` more generic in this case. Interrupts can be soft.